# Spinnaker Docker registry configuration

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to add Docker registry for Spinnaker using the below command:

> hal config provider docker-registry account add docker-registry-test
>   --address docker.xyz.com --repositories dept-test/test-apps/testsvc/test-service,dept-test/test-apps/testsvc1/test-service1
>   --username user --password

I would like to add more repositories under the same account.

How can I add repositories?

Also, I want all of my repositories available under dept-test. Whatever the repos available now and should display repos as and when it gets added.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to do that's actually not working?  From [the docs](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-provider-docker-registry-account-add) the `--repositories` flag says: "An optional list of repositories to cache images from. If not provided, Spinnaker will attempt to read accessible repositories from the registries _catalog endpoint". Doesn't seem like you need to list every repo you want to access out in this list. Is something you're trying to do (like pull an image from a Spinnaker pipeline) failing?

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration will get all images from your registry with 5 minutes cache refresh:

```
        dockerRegistry:
          enabled: true
          accounts:
          - name: docker-registry
            providerVersion: V1
            address: https://docker.cluster.local
            cacheIntervalSeconds: 300
            clientTimeoutMillis: 60000
            cacheThreads: 1
            paginateSize: 20
            sortTagsByDate: true
            trackDigests: false
            username: docker
            passwordFile: /data/accounts/docker-registry-password
```